# How to integrate Keycloak with Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, authentication, keycloak, jhipster

I'm trying to link my Flutter mobile app with a JHipster backend that uses Keycloak for authentication.
Does anyone have experience with integrating Keycloak with a Flutter application?

I've tried using several libraries, including:

- keycloak_flutter
- flutter_keycloak
- openid_client
- openidconnect
- flutter_appauth

However, most of these libraries seem deprecated or poorly documented, and I haven't been successful in integrating Keycloak with my Flutter app.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.